# Proving relation in boolean algebra, need help

Tags: boolean-algebra

Here is the logic equation and I am trying to prove the relation ($'$ stands for complement):
$$_1_3' + _2'_3' +_1_3 +_2'_3 = _1'_2' + _1_2 + _1_2'$$

What I am doing:
$$x_2' (x_1x_3' + x_1x_3 + x_3' + x_3)$$
$$x_2'(x_1(x_3' + x_3) + x_3' + x_3)$$
$$x_2'(x_1 + x_3' + x_3)$$

.. and I do not where to go further, $x_3' + x_3$ is a tautology but I think I cannot eliminate it when it is expression of ORs. It does not seem I am getting the expected result. Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: $+$ is disjunction, product is conjunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After drawing some Karnaugh maps, we have:
\begin{align*}
x_1x_3' + x_2'x_3' + x_1x_3 + x_2'x_3
&= (x_1 + x_2')x_3' + (x_1 + x_2')x_3 \\
&= (x_1 + x_2')(x_3' + x_3) \\
&= (x_1 + x_2')(1) \\
&= x_1 + x_2'
\end{align*}
Likewise, we have:
\begin{align*}
x_1'x_2' + x_1x_2 + x_1x_2'
&= x_1'x_2' + x_1x_2 + (x_1x_2' + x_1x_2') \\
&= (x_1x_2 + x_1x_2') + (x_1'x_2' + x_1x_2') \\
&= x_1(x_2 + x_2') + x_2'(x_1' + x_1) \\
&= x_1(1) + x_2'(1) \\
&= x_1 + x_2'
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to observe that both of these equations can be significantly simplified. $x_1x_2+x_1x_2'=x_1(x_2+x_2')=x_1$, so the right-hand side is equal to $x_1'x_2'+x_1=x_1'x_2'+x_1+x_1x_2'=x_1+x_2'$. Here I could add $x_1x_2'$ because $x_1x_2'\leq x_1$ so $x_1+x_1x_2'=x_1$. To reduce the left-hand side to this form is simple: just factor the $x_1$ and the $x_2'$ out of their respective terms.